# How to sort by First name in BibTeX?

Tags: bibtex

I am using BibTeX 0.99d, I am not defining any other code for reference packages. All I use is:

```
\bibliographystyle{abbrv} %Define style here
\bibliography{myFile} %Reference to my bib file
```

It works perfectly, but its sorted by last name, and the journal requires by first name.

I gave a read to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373569/bibliography-first-name-sorting), which is using another package, same case with [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334552/sort-references-by-first-author-and-then-year). Maybe I am missing something in my understanding of BibTeX vs Biber.

These are their requirements:
[image]

**UPDATE (SOLUTION)**

Thank you everyone, you were all right, there is no such a thing as order by First name, it was their mistake on the screenshot, I got confirmation already.

Comment: Do you have access to the file `abbrv.bst`?

Comment: Are you pulling our legs, or is there really a journal that requires sorting entries by authors’ given names?

Comment: @Mico I can get it, when I installed the environment in my Linux machine, all those dependencies where installed, so I have a centralized copy.

And I was also surprised... but unless I am missing something, they want that sorting, I will update the question with their instructions

Comment: The written instructions refer to alphabetical sorting. There’s absolutely no mention of sorting alphabeticallly by given names. I’d go with the standard sorting method, which is by surnames, and ignore the screenshot’s sorting method.

Comment: If this is the same journal as https://vtex-soft.github.io/texsupport.iospress-aac/ then they sort alphabetically by last name

Comment: Oh, an incredible coincidence the example is sorted by given name, it is very weird to give instructions about how to do something and provide an incorrect example.

Comment: The journal is https://www.iospress.nl/journal/intelligent-data-analysis/ but indeed is from IOS Press

Comment: Given that the references are numbered, the example looks most like an unsorted style, i.e., references appear in order of appearance in the text.  Whether that's the style they want or not is another issue, though.

Comment: Under “Manuscript submission & Author instructions” of your [linked site](https://www.iospress.nl/journal/intelligent-data-analysis/), the “REFERENCES” section contains only the first three entries in your picture. Coincidentally, the three entries are alphabetically ordered according to both first names and last names. I suspect the picture content was created by someone who wanted to include two more entries but was confused by this coincidence. Not to mention that you shouldn’t have *et al.* in the reference spot.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question was motivated by a miscommunication, resolved in comments, and there is no longer any question to answer.

Comment: I'd suggest deleting this question as there's no TeXnical question to answer (or, now, any question at all).

Comment: From the purely technical point of view, what if they would indeed wanted that (sort by the first name)? I tried and couldn't do it, maybe point out as an answer that better upgrade to Biber?